# rails controller for getting multiple table datas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller action

```
@posts = Post.where(sub_category_id: params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2).to_a
```

The post table contains category_id,sub_category_id,product_id. All there are three tables

Now i need the mapping name from the id. how can i achieve it.

I tried `@sub_category = SubCategory.find params[:id]`  to get sub category it works fine.

Whether above method is good? If yes how can i achieve it to get other table datas.

**Edit-1**

I am having table post with following fields

1. id
2. category_id
3. sub_category_id
4. product_id
5. title

I am having following set of tables

1. category
2. sub category
3. product

In my view my `title` is hyperlink. When i click on it. It will redirect to respected post page and i have to show a `breadcrum` like this `Electronics->Laptop->Dell`

**Edit-2**

I tried it but getting error as

```
undefined method `category_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post:0xb4e7a9f0>
```

Tried the following

```
  @posts = Post.where(sub_category_id: params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2).to_a
  @category = Category.find(@posts.category_id) unless @posts.blank?
```

Comment: There may be a language barrier here, but it is hard to understand your question.

Comment: @tyler Please check my `edit 1` for better understanding what i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add params in link, **something like this:**

```
<a href='/controller/post?category_id=1&sub_category_id=2&product_id=3'>click-here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `post` in your `show` or other action, you can get your values like so:

```
# PostsController#show
...
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@category = Category.find(@post.category_id)
@sub_category = SubCategory.find(@post.sub_category_id)
@product = Product.find(@post.product_id)
```

Then in your view:

```
# show.html.erb
...
<%= @category.name + ">>" + @sub_category.name + ">>" + @product.name %>
```

This assumes you have a `.name` method on each to get the text that you want.  You will also need to handle the cases where a `Category`/`SubCategory`/`Product` is not found, in which case you will get `nil`.  You can't call the `.name` method on `nil`, so you would need to do something to handle that case.  One example of how to do this, if you only need the text from `Category` and no other information:

```
@category = Category.find(@post.category_id)
@category_name = @category.name unless @category.blank?
```

Comment: `@posts` is a collection (an `Array`), which you use in your `index` action. `@post` (singular) is a specific `Post`, which you typically set in your `show` action.  You cannot call a method from the model `Post` on an `Array`.  Notice that I did not suggest you call the method `.category_id` on `@posts`, I suggested you call it on `@post`, which is a specific `Post`.